# Download the file or picture of the user with the bot Telegram

Tags: php, telegram-bot

How to download any file the user and stored on the server I was sent a telegram to the bot ?

I am working with PHP language

Comment: As a new SO member, I would suggest please go through this section [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Telegram bot - receive photo URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991698/telegram-bot-receive-photo-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this method from Telegram Bot API documentation:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile