# Looking up media Url from a TL.Message using WTelegram.Client

Tags: c#, .net-core, wtelegramclient

I'd like to look up media URLs associated with various objects returned by the `WTelegram.Client`:

```
var resolved = await client.Contacts_ResolveUsername(peerName);
```

`resolved.Chat.Photo` has a `photo_id` and judging by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36166942/88513) to a different question, there's supposed to be a way to convert that to an URL. Is that possible using the `WTelegram.Client`? To be clear, I don't want to download the media. I just want to hotlink to it.

**Update:** I was referring to public channels and forums. Not private chats of anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telegram is a cryptographically-secure messenger platform that ensure your messages and data exchange are not accessible to anyone.

Hence you cannot access its content directly from the web via hotlinking.

Comment: I have clarified my question. So you have to download the media and serve it yourself I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Some public channels can be accessed on the web via https://t.me/s/CHANNELNAME

Example: https://t.me/s/spacex